# jQuery escape certain html entities only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a little profile system with mentions in place

The 'content' value in my Posts table is stored as:

```
<a href="/profile/Alice">Alice</a> Alice, you there? &lt;strong&gt;lol&lt;/strong&gt;
```

- the a href Profile link is generated by my system (I replace all mentions with a html link to the profile)
- the <strong>lol</strong> are user-defined HTML that I do not wish to display (I use htmlentities() on all user-posts so their html input becomes that)

However, the end-result is everything being shown as HTML (I display them using json and jquery). How can I make it such that it only shows the  in HTML (for my mention links), but not all the user-specified ones? (i.e. <strong>)

I want the post to display the mentions in hyper link, but at the same time, I do not want all user entered html to be displayed as html.

I use jQuery append to display my posts.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a bit on the terminology used in your post? Is "message in my database" same as "user-posts"? And how do you define/detect a "mention"? And what do you mean by "only shows the in HTML"? is there a grammar typo there?

Comment: @light Hey, I tried to explain it better now.

Comment: I still don't understand how "mentions" are generated/detected. Also don't understand what you mean by the seemingly grammatically incorrect "shows the in HTML". Also, there's a new one "the are generated by my system". The *what* are generated?

Comment: @light apologies, that part did not show as i included a html tag and it was hidden. I've also tried to re-explain. So sorry!

Comment: To add code inline in your question, enclose them in backticks `

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<a href="/profile/Alice">Alice</a> Alice, you there? &lt;strong&gt;lol&lt;/strong&gt;';
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
echo $str;
exit;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work here. Maybe I should be clearer - I want my jQuery to just show the html e.g <ahref></a> but not those like &lt; - because those htmlentities are user-specified, while the <ahref> are done by the system and are safe to display.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, I think this will do it. `find("*")` only matches HTML tags, so the text nodes outside the tags are filtered out.

```js
var content = '<a href="/profile/Alice">Alice</a> Alice, you there? &lt;strong&gt;lol&lt;/strong&gt;';
var wrapped = $("<div>", { html: content });

$("#output").append(wrapped.find("*"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I wrap it in a `DIV` first, because `.find()` only searches children, not the top-level nodes.